# tidyverse `arrange()` looping over a vector

Tags: r, dplyr

Is there a way to loop over a vector of column names used in `arrange()`?

```r
library(tidyverse)
mpg <- mpg |> slice(1:2) |> select(1:4)
mpg
#> # A tibble: 2 × 4
#>   manufacturer model displ  year
#>   <chr>        <chr> <dbl> <int>
#> 1 audi         a4      1.8  1999
#> 2 audi         a4      1.8  1999

cols <- names(mpg)[1:4]
mpg_arranged <- mpg |> 
  arrange(
    desc(.data[[cols[1]]]),
    desc(.data[[cols[2]]]),
    desc(.data[[cols[3]]]),
    desc(.data[[cols[4]]])
  )
mpg_arranged
#> # A tibble: 2 × 4
#>   manufacturer model displ  year
#>   <chr>        <chr> <dbl> <int>
#> 1 audi         a4      1.8  1999
#> 2 audi         a4      1.8  1999
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: like `|> arrange(across(1:4, desc))` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use across: `arrange(across(all_of(cols), desc))`

Comment: `all_of(cols)` or `any_of(cols)`